# bounded linear functions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I am currently working on the following problem:

Let $(G,⟨·,·⟩)$ be a euclidean vector space. $G$ is a normalized vector space with $\|x\|:=\sqrt{⟨x,x⟩}$.
Moreover, let $v ∈ G$.

(a) Show that $C_v: G \to\mathbb R, u \mapsto ⟨u,v⟩$ defines a bounded, linear functional on $G$.

(b) Determine $\|C_v\|:= \inf \{B>0 :|C_v u|≤B\cdot\|u\| ∀u ∈ G\}$

for a) I thought about using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as $|⟨x,y⟩|≤ \|x\|\cdot\|y\|$ but I'm not sure how to do it properly.
what is the best way to approach b)?

If you have any ideas how to solve this problem, I would be happy if you let me know!

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: This seems wrong to me. If you take $G=\mathbb{R}^n$, $<x,x>$ the canonical inner product, and $v=(1,…,1)$, then $C_v$ is not bounded (consider the vectors $u_p=(p,…,p)$ as $p$ goes to infinity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track for a). The linearity of $C_v$ should be clear by the properties of an inner product. And from
$$|C_v(u)| = |\langle u,v \rangle| \le ||u|| \cdot ||v||$$
we obtain, that $C_v$ is in fact bounded because boundedness of an operator $A$ means: There is a $C>0$ such that $||Ax|| \le C ||x||$ for all $x$. Here this is the case as we see $v$ as a fixed vector, so $||v||$ is the desired constant.

We also see from this argument, thatt $||C_v|| \le ||v||$. Now we could guess that in fact $||C_v||=||v||$ is true. To prove that we have to find a vector $u$ that satisfies $|C_v(u)| = ||u|| \cdot ||v||$. We know when this is the case because we know that we have equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality if $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent, so for example we can pick $u=v$ and get
$$|C_v(v)| = |\langle v,v \rangle| = ||v||^2$$
and from that we obtain $||C_v||=||v||$.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your help! There's only one more question left: the linearity is practically clear, but I still don't know how to prove it. Would you mind showing me how to do it properly? :(

Comment: Yes, you need to check if $C_v(u+w) = C_v(u) + C_v(w)$. We get $C_v(u+w) = \langle u+w, v \rangle = \langle u,v \rangle + \langle w,v \rangle = C_v(u) + C_v(w)$ from the properties of the inner product. Then we can also see $C_v( \lambda u) = \langle \lambda u, v \rangle = \lambda \langle u,v \rangle = \lambda C_v(u)$ and from that we see that $C_v$ is linear.

Comment: Ahh thanks I got it! Do you know if I still need to prove $v≠0$? because $||v||=0$ for $v=0$ so $C=0$ but not $C>0$?

Comment: You don't need that: We have $||C_v||=||v||$ which will stay true for $v=0$, because then $C_v=0$.

Answer (score 0):

(a)
For given $v \in G$, use Cauchy-Schwartz inequality
$$ |C_v u| = |\langle u,v\rangle | \leq \|u\|\cdot\|v\|$$
Therefore $C_v$ is bounded with constant $\|v\|$.

(b)
Lets show that |C_v| = |v|.
Lets assume that |v| is not |Cv|. Therefore there must exist some $\varepsilon > 0$ and  $u \in G$ such that
$$|C_v u| + \varepsilon \leq \|u\|\cdot \|v\|$$
But if we pick $u = v$, then $|C_v v| = \|v\|^2$, so
$$||v||^2 + \varepsilon \leq \|v\|^2$$
which means $ \varepsilon \leq 0$. But this is a contradiction, therefore $\|C_v\| = \|v\|$.